# Define the size of an image by its height IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm doing a webpage where i need to define the image by its height. It can be either `height:100%;` to have the same height than its parent or `height:5vh` because his parent is 5vh height. I'm letting the width to its default value `width:auto;`

All this code works well but i need a compatibility for IE9 and the image on this browser does not resize when i only define its height.

HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <img id="logo" src="img/myPic.png" alt="myPic">
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
.container{
height:5vh;
}

.red {
width:10px;
height:5vh;
background-color: #E92426;
position:relative;
float:left;
}

#logo {
margin-left:3%;
height:100%;
// OR height:5vh; ( I tried both )
}
```

Do you know what I should adjust to make it compatible with IE9 ?

**EDIT :** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lser421/)

Comment: It would be good if you had a jsfiddle to help explain the problem. Its sometimes easier to see the problem along with the code. IE in general is a bit sketchy in the way that it handles `vh` even IE11 does not fully support all aspects of it. You can use media queries to do the same thing you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I get something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lser421/) it works well on everything but IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple things over and over and in the end I surrendered placing  elements relative to each other. ( image height relative to parent height )

I changed my HTML to :

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<img id="logo" src="img/myPic.png" alt="myPic">
```

And my CSS to :

```
.container {
    background-color : #323A41;
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.red {
    width:10px;
    height:5%;
    background-color: #E92426;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
}

#logo {
    height:5%;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:5%;
    z-index:10;
}
```

So basically i put `position:absolute` to everything.

I am aware that this is probably not the best solution for my question but for the time, it works.

PS : feel free to add a better answer and I'll accept it if it works :)